# CRA typescript lint

Tags: reactjs, eslint, tslint, react-scripts

I want to setup a command on my package.json that can do the TS files linting on my react App (using CRA that provides the app with react-scripts 3.1.2).

I saw that tslint is getting deprecated and that's why the react community is moving to ESlint.

There are some clues on the package.json file, like:

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
```

So my idea is that when I run the eslint, it can take that configuration and use all the CRA setup.

I tried :

```
"lint" : "eslint --ext=jsx,ts,tsx src"
```

But no luck, since I put some errors on the code and it still do not show me any information.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried `"eslint --ext .jsx,.ts,.tsx src"`?

Comment: yeap.... I tried that, even taking out types to break the app, adding spaces, etc.

Comment: this [document](https://dev.to/benweiser/how-to-set-up-eslint-typescript-prettier-with-create-react-app-3675) may help you.

Comment: Do you have a `.eslintrc.js` file? What parser is set?

Comment: @DragonWhite thanks! i'm taking a look at that. It surprise me that a simple lint can lead to lot's of researching on react-scripts. I will try that!

Comment: @Tim I want to reuse the config from react-scripts (created by CRA), that is on the eslintConfig attribute on package.json, so I do not duplicate code and standards of CRA

Comment: As long as you haven't committed a lot of time into your app, there is actually native typescript version of CRA that does all that work for you https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter

Comment: @Andrew yes... i know that one, but it is deprecated now. I will somo more research on how to make work standard CRA with TS on that linting thing

Answer (score 0):

So I found a good approach. My idea was to keep everything working with the CRA standards and reuse everything (not sure why nobody adds this on the CRA, probably I will add a PR on the future to check)

This fixed the thing, reusing all the dependencies that CRA uses:

On package.json (standard for CRA)

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",     
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ]
  }
```

And then you can add a lint script:

```
    "lint" : "eslint ./src/**/*.{tsx,ts}",
```

I hope that this will help someone :-)

Also, if someone knows more about the good practice on this, it will be very appreciated!

PD: .eslintignore is also working fine